# Data not being pulled when typing keyword in the search box

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have search feature that I setup. When I type the keyword in I get no records back and no error message. Just the table header. I see the department other in the database. When I type it in the keyword box I get nothing back.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="">
  <table width="599" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Keyword
      <input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value="<?php echo $_GET["txtKeyword"];?>">
      <input type="submit" value="Search"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<?php
if($_GET["txtKeyword"] != "")
    {
        $serverName = "localhost";
    $objConnect = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=maintenance", "TestUser", "test") or die("Error Connect to Database");

    // Search By lanId or department
    $objQuery = $objConnect->prepare("SELECT  * FROM requests  WHERE (lanId LIKE '%".$_GET["txtKeyword"]."%' or department LIKE '%".$_GET["txtKeyword"]."%' )  ");

    ?>
    <table width="600" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th width="91"> <div align="center">lanId </div></th>
        <th width="98"> <div align="center">Name </div></th>
        <th width="198"> <div align="center">department </div></th>

      </tr>
    <?php

        while( $objResult = $objQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo $objResult["lanId"];?></div></td>
        <td><?php echo $objResult["name"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objResult["department"];?></td>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like print_r($objQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); to see if you're actually pulling data?

Comment: just tried that nothing is coming up wonder why

Comment: Oh sorry, instead of calling fetch(), try fetchAll() like this: "print_r($objQuery->fetchAll());".

Comment: it shows this Array ( )

Comment: so, apart from being opened to sql injection, did you consider the possibility that your research actually yields nothing? `Array ()` means that the query was successful, but returned nothing.

Comment: how is it open for sql injections I am using PDO prepared statments and yes I knew it was not returning data just posted what the page read

Comment: I had a feeling it was something i was missing I just missed the excute() statment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `prepare()` statement you should  also use `execute()` :
http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/pdo-prepare-execute

Comment: that was it I forgot to put the objQuery->execute();